# How to control Turtlebot3 in Gazebo using a web interface?

Tags: html, ros, robot, gazebo-simu

If I have a simulated Turtlebot3 robot in Gazebo, how could I link it and control its movement using a self-made HTML/Bootstrap web interface (website?) I have tried many tutorials but none of them have worked (may be because they are all from a few years ago). Would appreciate any recent links or tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by installing gazebo, gzweb, turtlebot3 package.
What is gzweb?

> GzWeb is usually installed on an Ubuntu server. Gzweb is a client for
> Gazebo which runs on a web browser. Once the server is set up and
> running, clients can interact with the simulation simply by accessing
> the server's URL on a web browser.

For gazebo and gzweb installation follow: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gzweb_install&cat=gzweb

After creating a package using catkin create a python file turtlebot3_move_gz.py and add the following code to the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist    

def talker():
  rospy.init_node('vel_publisher')
  pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
  rate = rospy.Rate(2)
  move = Twist() # defining the way we can allocate the values
  move.linear.x = 0.5 # allocating the values in x direction - linear
  move.angular.z = 0.0  # allocating the values in z direction - angular

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  pub.publish(move)
  rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
      talker()
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

### Save the file

### Next steps

In terminal:

1. Launch Gazebo simulator turtlebot3:
   roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch
2. Start gzwebserver in a new terminal. On the server machine, start gazebo or gzserver first, it's recommended to run in verbose mode so you see debug messages:

   gzserver --verbose
3. Fire up another terminal to start npm:

   npm start
4. run your python turtlebot3 file in catkin_ws directory:

   rosrun name_of_the_package turtlebot3_move_gz.py
5. Open a browser that has WebGL and websocket support (i.e. most modern browsers) and point it to the IP address and port where the HTTP server is started, for example:

   http://localhost:8080
6. To stop gzserver or the GzWeb servers, just press Ctrl+C in their terminals.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something I have done before, but with a quick search I found some useful information.

You need to use [`rosbridge_suite`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite?distro=melodic) and in specific [`rosbridge_server`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_server). The latter provides a low-latency bidirectional communication layer between a web browser and servers. This allows a website to talk to ROS using the rosbridge protocol.

Therefore, you need to have this suite installed and then what you can do is to use it to publish a `Twist` message from the website (based on the website UI controls) to Turtlebot's command topic.

Don't think of Gazebo in this equation. Gazebo is the simulator and is using under-the-hood ROS topics and services to simulate the robot. What you really need to focus on is how to make your website talk with ROS and publish a Twist message to the appropriate ROS topic.

I also found a JavaScript library from ROS called [`roslibjs`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs) that implements the `rosbridge` protocol specification. You can, therefore, use JavaScript to communicate with ROS and publish robot velocities to the TurtleBot.

An example excerpt from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) tutorial (not tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var cmdVel = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/cmd_vel',
    messageType : 'geometry_msgs/Twist'
  });

  var twist = new ROSLIB.Message({
    linear : {
      x : 0.1,
      y : 0.2,
      z : 0.3
    },
    angular : {
      x : -0.1,
      y : -0.2,
      z : -0.3
    }
  });

  cmdVel.publish(twist);
</script>
```

As you can see above the JavaScript code creates an instance of the Twist message with the linear and angular robot velocities and then publishes this message to ROS's `/cmd_vel` topic. What you need to do is to integrate this into your website, make the velocities in this code to be dynamic based on the website UI controls and start the `rosbridge` server.